# python - requests timeout for the whole request?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am crawling many sites for data, but some links are freezing my script permanently. This shouldn't happen, since I used a timeout like this :

```
page = requests.get(url,timeout=4)
```

I want a timeout for the whole request. So when the request take 4 seconds it will stop trying.
I searched `requests` documentation, and I found this code for read and connect timeout:

```
r = requests.get(url, timeout=(3.05, 27))
```

However, I get a type error when I try and use it:

```
Timeout value connect was (3.05, 27), but it must be an int or float.
```

How can I get the timeout I want?

Comment: what version of requests?

Comment: What is requests? We need more of the code.. Have you also considered using urllib2? It can have the timeout set as well, and handle opening URLs, and even handle requesting specific data

Comment: @Vincenzzzochi, requests is a very well known http lib http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/

Comment: how do i get the version i forget it :p

Comment: pip freeze | grep request, if you used pip to install your app (to get thte version)

Comment: `import requests;requests.__version__`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on a related [issue here](https://github.com/docker/docker-py/issues/377) with docker, it is a bug in `python-requests` that has been fixed in  `python-requests version 2.4.3-4`. Upgrade to the latest version and you should be fine.

If you have pip use `pip install -U requests`

Comment: not solved :/ 
`Downloading/unpacking requests
Installing collected packages: requests
Successfully installed requests
Cleaning up...` and i still get the same error : `Timeout value connect was (8, 8), but it must be an int or float.`

Comment: ok, what does  `import requests;requests.__version__`  output?

Comment: hmmm that's correct i still get '2.3.0' what i suppose to do ? restart my computer or something ? tnx alot ^^

Comment: how did you install? I mean originally. Also python2 or 3?

Comment: with pip >>> `pip install -U requests`
and i get : `Downloading/unpacking requests Installing collected packages: requests Successfully installed requests Cleaning up...`

Comment: I meant originally, also your python version is important

Comment: mmmm ok my python is 2.7.9 i'll try to unistall requests and retry :)

Comment: mmm you mean in the first place ? i got it from my old win7

Comment: also just try `pip2 install -U requests`

Comment: If you have the latest the version should be `'2.5.3'`. You are using a very old version.

Comment: @FreeSteampowresGames, no worries, usually when you come across what seems to be  a bug, upgrading to the latest  package can be the solution. It is good practice to keep you packages fairly up to date. If you run `pip list -o` it will list all your installed packages with a more recent version available.

Answer (score 0):

> as AntoineGa commented on May 12

https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/4761

downgrade urllib3 to 1.26.15, it works for me

```
pip install urllib3==1.26.15
```